# Swift how to make a variable global in a file, but not share to other files

Tags: swift

I'm wanting to declare some global variables in a file, so that I can use them in different functions in that file, but when I do this, I see that I can reference them in a different swift file. Is there a way to make it so that they stay global but cant be referenced from a different file. I'd like to be able to copy and paste a lot of code from one file into another, but at the moment when I do I get 'invalid redeclaration' error. Is there any solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the variable after the class declaration, you should have access to it throughout that file but not in other files. For example:

```
class Hello: UIViewController {

  var myVariable: String = "" // This Variable accessible throughout the  file
}
```

Comment: ah i see now, i was putting it in the didmovetoview() method. Puting it above that but below the class declaration works

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wanting to declare some global variables in a file, so that I can
>   use them in different functions in that file.but when I do this, I see that I can reference them in a different swift file

If you would like to use the variable only in the class, declare it as a private instead of public.

```
class MyClass: UIViewController {

  private var myVariable: String = "" // myVariable is private now

}
```

Please note that, variables or fields that are declared public have no accessibility restrictions. A private member, however, is only visible in its class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create global variable check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

```
 class CommonFunctions{
  // Example for global
   struct GlobalVariable {
            let screenheight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height;
            let screenwidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width;
        }

 }
```

To use the variable in other View Controllers

```
 CommonFunctions.GlobalVariable().screenheight
```